# How do I get from the marked lantern to the hot tub without touching any snow?

Tags: here-comes-niko

In The Bathhouse, after getting the Contract List from Tadpole HQ, the Game Kid has a mission to jump from the marked lantern to the indicated hot tub without touching any snow.

How do I get to this hot tub without touching any snow or water?

[image: game kid]

Comment: _the Game Kid has a mission to swim ..._ How can one swim at all without touching water??

Comment: @JohnGordon Oops copy and paste error. Fixed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst the wooden poles in the water may look tempting, I don't think they're actually helpful. Here's one approach:

Jump and dive to just about reach the ladder (1), then climb up this area only touching the stone boulders (2-6).

[image: stage 1]

From here, jump onto the bridge (1), then the ladder (2), rooftop (3), and upper bridge (4).

[image: stage 2]

Almost there! Jump down onto the wooden painting platform (1), then bounce across the umbrellas (2-4) to finally land in the hot tub (5).

[image: stage 3]